# Translate messages inside twig in symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to access to the translations via twig.

For example, I have the name of my application inside my `Resources/translations/messages.de.yml` and `Resources/translations/messages.en.yml`

My controller does only a render of the twig file.

And inside my twig-file I want to access to the application.name property which is defined inside the messages-file (yml)

How can I access to this property to get the application name (let's say it contains some language-specific information)

I tried these methods, and failed:

- `{{ application.name }}`

  - Looks more like for variables which have been sent through the controller, I've got an error, that the variable 'application' was not found
- `{% trans% } application.name {% endtrans %}`

  - displays application.name
- `{% trans% } 'application.name' {% endtrans %}`

  - displays 'application.name'

Comment: Can you show us the content of your `messages.en.yml` ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With inline notation you should use filter:

```
{{ 'application.name'|trans }}
```

With `trans` tag I think problem in whitespaces around application.name

Comment: Don't forget to mention (I know is not asked but just gave a best answer) that if the message is not defined in the default domain the translation is done with {{ 'application.name' | trans ({}, 'domain') }}

Comment: Thanks, somehow I had also this commented out in my app/config/config.yml file (i don't know why): framework.translator:      { fallback: %locale% }

Answer (score -1):

```
{% trans% }app.name{% endtrans %}
```

In your messages.en.yml

```
<trans-unit id="app.name" resname="app.name">
    <source>My app</source>
    <target>My app</target>
  </trans-unit>
```

In your messages.de.yml

```
 <trans-unit id="app.name" resname="app.name">
    <source>My app</source>
    <target>Meine App</target>
  </trans-unit>
```